# What's the hunter labor in the DFHack 'manipulator' plugin?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In the [*manipulator*](http://dfhack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/Plugins.html#manipulator) plugin screen there's nothing labeled 'hunter'. What's the name of the labor for hunting? "Ambusher"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ambusher** is indeed the skill associated with the **Hunting** labor.

[Link to relevant wiki article](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Ambusher)

Just to confirm, images below using Manipulator and Dwarf Therapist. You can see that Udil's role is **Hunter** and they only have experience as in **Ambushing**. In both tools they have Hunting (H in manipulator) enabled. Both tools also list Ambushing as the actual skill.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I read that page too. But the first sentence implies, in my reading, that there *is* a 'hunting' labor, separate from the ambusher skill, that can be enabled or disabled: "Dwarves with the hunting labor enabled automatically use the ambusher skill ...".

Comment: @KennyEvitt I've added some additional detail to my answer. It might be written that way because hunters also use the marksdwarf skill to attack animals.